# How do I complete the Darkmoon Faire quest 'The Humanoid Cannonball' in one go?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

So I was wondering if someone could tell me when you have to get rid of the wings to land a bullseye everytime. Probably a gauged camera angle would be great (lets say top bottom view).

Comment: Unless they fixed it, the easiest way to get the achievement was to have a friend summon you to the center of the circle. Have Group Will Travel or a Warlock summon (which would require extra people to accomplish). Have them summon you so the message appears on your screen, jump in the cannon, as soon as you are launched click Accept on the summon. Achievement!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Blastenheimer Bullseye achievement may take a few attempts, but essentially you want to lose your wings just after passing over the pier:

[image: Where to release]

Keep in mind that you can be fired out of the cannon even without the quest, although if you have the quest then getting a bullseye will give you all 5 required cannon target points to complete the quest.

I have heard that the latest version of Deadly Boss Mods as of WoW patch 4.3.2 supports a warning telling you when to release from your wings, however I do not use DBM myself so cannot confirm this.

[This comment](http://www.wowhead.com/quest=29436/the-humanoid-cannonball#comments:id=1589098) on WoW Head also indicates that it is possible to create a temporary addon that will help with this achievement if you're struggling, although I have also never used this myself either.

Comment: I think installing the deadly boss mod would give you a count down in a female's voice.

Comment: Yeah, I use bigwigs though and have never used DBM - I was just using Google-fu to investigate the answer to this :P

Comment: Confirmed DBM has had a warning/countdown to let you know when to jump. Of course if you have high latency even with a warning you can sometimes still miss.